# Fetch Postgres optimizations and JIT compiled code

Tags: postgresql, optimization, internals

I am currently writing a benchmark tool that compares different DBMS with each other.

Is there a way to output all optimizations passed through the optimizer and even the generated assembly of the JIT compiler if applicable?

I don't need the execution plan in the first place but only a sequence of the optimizations passed through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you can get are the statistics at the end of the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output.